# Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement

Tags: maven, javafx, h2

I have a problem with my JavaFX CRUD application. Here is the code:

```
 ObservableList<Data> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        try {
            DBConnection DBConnection = new DBConnection();
            Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM DATA");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while(result.next()) {
                dataList.add(new Data(
                        result.getString("name"),
                        result.getString("category"),
                        result.getInt("price"),
                        result.getString("date"))
                );
            }
            table.setItems(dataList);
            fillTableWithData();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
 @FXML
    void addBtn(ActionEvent event) {

        String name = nameField.getText();
        String category = categoryField.getText();
        int price = priceField.getAnchor();
        String date = "2023-01-01";

        String query = "INSERT INTO DATA VALUES ('abcdef','food',10,'1991-01-01')";


        try {
            DBConnection DBConnection = new DBConnection();
            Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Data data = new Data(name, category, price, date);
        table.getItems().add(data);
    }
```

```
private void fillTableWithData() {
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        categoryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("category"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
    }
```

As you can see, I have a initialize method (which has to connect project with H2 Embedded database and show data from it in the JavaFX table). This part is working, the data from database is showing in table after run of the project. Second thing is the addBtn method, which has to add new data to database by writing this data in GUI. Here is the problem - newly added data shows in the table, but not in the database. So I need to create some method or whatever to autosave newly added data from GUI. I don't want to create new separate saveButton, I want to make addBtn method simultaneously autosave with adding a data to table.

I know how to pull out data from database to table, but I don't know how to do it vice versa - from table to database.

I don't know what means this error from IDE: "Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement". That error show off cause of query in the addBtn method. Data in this query are exemplery. Initially I gave the entered in GUI data there (from nameField.getText() etc.), but I thought that the error appears because of the syntax, so I entered this data to check the program. Despite this, the error appears.

Do you have any ideas? What's wrong with my code? How can I put entered data in GUI to database?

I am using JavaFX, H2 Embedded Database and Maven.

Comment: It’s not really clear what we can tell you other than what is already stated in the error message. The error occurs on the line where you call `executeQuery()` and the error message tells you to use `execute()` or `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()`. Did you try that? What happened?

Comment: If your actual question is really about why there are different methods, maybe this helps. A *query* typically returns data, possibly large quantities of data. The return type of `executeQuery()` is `ResultSet` which is a class that encapsulates the potentially-large data set. An SQL `INSERT` statement doesn’t return data, so it doesn’t make any sense to call it in a method that returns a `ResultSet`. Call `executeUpdate(…)` instead, which returns an `int`, representing the number of rows inserted into the table.

Answer (score 3):

### SQLException

Note this has nothing to do with JavaFX, or even H2 specifically. This is a restriction mandated by the [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html). From the documentation of [`PreparedStatement#executeQuery()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()), that method is defined to throw a `SQLException` if:

> a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed `PreparedStatement` **or the SQL statement does not return a `ResultSet` object** *[emphasis added]*

The emphasized part is the important part here. You prepared the statement with the following:

> ```sql
> INSERT INTO DATA VALUES ('abcdef','food',10,'1991-01-01')
> ```

But an `INSERT` will not return a `ResultSet`<sup>**1**</sup>. Thus, as the exception states, you must call either [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()), which can execute any kind of SQL statement, or [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()), which can only execute SQL statements that *do not* return a `ResultSet`, on the `PreparedStatement`.

### Concurrency

Note you have another issue with your code, though it won't result in an exception being thrown. You are executing database-accessing code on the *JavaFX Application Thread*. The FX thread is responsible for handling user-generated events and scheduling render "pulses". That means you must never block or execute long-running tasks on the FX thread, lest you cause the application to become unresponsive.

Two decent online resources for learning about concurrency in JavaFX include:

- [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm#JFXIP546)
- The documentation of the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package and the types contained therein.

---

<sup>**1.** A `SELECT` statement is the quintessential type of statement to use with `executeQuery()`, though there may be others, including database-specific queries.</sup>